# Running tophat dockerfile in background

Tags: sequence-alignment, bash, docker

I need to use tophat2 to align some sequences, and I wish to use the docker container. These are large sequences so it will take a long time, plus I'm working on a university server so the chances of being kicked off the server are very high. How can I use nohup and & to run tophat2 through docker, if I need some user interaction?

Comment: Do you have root access? Docker generally requires root (as it normally is systemctl service and hard/janky to use otherwise)... Does the server not have a queuing system? Or is this a classic furtive job in the login node of an oversubscribed cluster? Also if an admin may kill a nohup job, they may kill your docker job.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your user is in the group permitted to use docker:

```
docker pull quay.io/biocontainers/tophat:2.1.1--py27_3
nohup docker run -v /some/path:/data quay.io/biocontainers/tophat:2.1.1--py27_3 tophat2 ... &
```

The only thing to remember is to mount everything you'll need into the docker container (`/data` in the example above). If you need to debug things then you can add the `-it` flag to `docker run` and use `bash` as the command.

As an aside, you might find using `screen` or `tmux` preferable to `nohup ... &`, since you can reconnect to sessions with them.